# How To log off a user when he is disconnected through the Web SignalR Hub?

Tags: signalr

Hope everyone is well.
I'm using MVC C# , AspNet.Identities and have a fully functional Account controller.

I recently introduced a basic SignalR Hub to the project, I want to log the user out once he disconnects from the Hub. My idea is to call the LogOff method from the Account Controller.

The Hub is really simple, infact I've taken this from a video by Scott Hanselman if I'm not mistaken. Just the hitCounter part...Now I'm trying to add in the logoff() functionality.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
    }//this is in my account controller


[Authorize]
[HubName("hitCounter")]
public class GameplayHub : Hub
{
        private static int intCounter = 0;

        public void RecordHit()
        {
            intCounter += 1;
            this.Clients.All.onHitRecorded(intCounter);
        }

        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            Final.Controllers.AccountController obj = new Final.Controllers.AccountController();
            intCounter -= 1;
            this.Clients.All.onHitRecorded(intCounter);
            this.Clients.Caller.onHitRecorded(obj.LogOff());
            obj.LogOff();

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);

        }

}//this is the hub


<div id="hitCount" style="font-size:50px;"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var con=$.hubConnection();
        var hub=con.createHubProxy('hitCounter');
        hub.on('onHitRecorded', function (i) {
            $('#hitCount').text(i);
        });
        con.start(function() {
            hub.invoke('recordHit');
        });
    })
</script>//My view...just shows how many people active at that point...
```

The amount of people active, shows correctly. What I'm trying to do in my app is, if a user in on 2 tabs, and he closes one, he must be logged off on both.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntelny it is not going to work. Logging off user is done by removing cookie which has to be done by browser. SignalR runs your disconnected handler after tab was already closed, so you can not tell browser to delete cookie.

The solution that could work is to force redirect to log off page on the second tab opened by user.

Pseudocode:

In SignalR hub:

```
Task OnDisconnected()
{
  var otherTab = FindOtherTabWithUser();
  otherTab.forceLogOff();
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
forceLogOff = function() { window.location.href = '/logoff'; }
```